# Check if selenium webdriver is being detected?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

is there any way to check when runninng selenium webdriver from python or puppeteer from javascript if the website that i'm visiting is detecting that i'm running a bot? are there any websites that tell you if you would fail a bot test? (ex.: cloudflare or captcha)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's the bot test for Cloudflare: https://nowsecure.nl (If Selenium/automation is detected, it will keep loading the page forever. If you bypassed detection, you'll see blinking lights that you passed.)

There's a Python library that lets you get past that bot blocker: [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

That tool has been integrated into [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) so that you can bypass bot detection as a pytest command-line option (`--uc`) for your Selenium Python tests:
`pytest --uc`.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the answer. i managed to find a couple more resources. here is a list of everything i found:

```
https://nowsecure.nl/ (thanks to user Michael Mintz)
https://bot.sannysoft.com
https://browserleaks.com/
https://bot.incolumitas.com/
https://fingerprintjs.github.io/fingerprintjs/
https://antoinevastel.com/bots/
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/
```

out of all the websites i found browserleaks and incolumnitas to be the most comprehensive. i'll leave the question open, feel free anyone to add some more if you know.